# Perl Mechanize Click A Radio Button

Tags: perl, mechanize

I am trying to click a radio button by using Perl with Mechanize module . I tried

```
$mech->find_all_inputs ( name => "name" , value => "1" )
```

, but could not get any result. The html code of the radio button is like that;

```
<input name="name" value="1" type="radio">
```

And there are other radio buttons with the same name but different values.So how can I click the radio button using Mechanize module?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I actually get it , but could not understand how can I specify to click the radio button with value "1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user agent cannot magically distinguish the right one. Find them all, and then go through them and pick the one(s) you need. You can learn values by the method `possible_values`

```
# Finding the field name and values for the radio element
foreach ( $ua->find_all_inputs(type => 'radio') ) {
    $radio_name = $_->name;
    say "$radio_name values: " . join('|', $_->possible_values)
}
```

If it's just one

```
my ($radio_name, $input_err) = 
    map $_->name, $ua->find_all_inputs(type => 'radio');
warn "More radio inputs than expected: $!" if defined($input_err);
```

Once you have the right button you can fill the form in which it is. For example

```
$ua->submit_form( fields => { $radio_name => 'AND' });
```

The `submit_form` "*lets you select a form from the previously fetched page, fill in its fields, and submit it.*" [from docs, [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.75/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)]. It takes parameters as hashes, where you can set names and values, for example.  This method is a higher-level wrapper, instead of which you can use more specific ones, for example

```
$ua->field( $name, $value );
```

To set a field among duplicate ones, pick the number of the one you want. For example, to set the second one from the list

```
$ua->set_fields( $name => [ 'field_value', 2 ] )
```

Also note that `WWW::Mechanize` inherits heavily.  When you search for the right call it may be a good idea to look through methods in the packages that it inherits from.

Comment: @ccca Welcome -- I added a bit more, to make it more useful.  Let me know if it needs else/more.